# How to define and trigger Backbone route with get params?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

I have the following routes:

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "": "index"
  },

  index: function() {
    ...
  }       
});
```

At now I can trigger this route like this `Backbone.history.navigate('', true);` and all works fine. But now I need to add `GET` params to that router to be possible trigger and handle route like this:

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "?:query": "index"
  },

  index: function(query) {
    ...
  }       
});
```

But unfortunately my `index` callback don't get executed when I trigger `Backbone.history.navigate('?needShowPopup=true', true);`

How should I define and trigger route to pass and handle `GET` parameters for my `index` route?

Answer (score 0):

I would do that

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "*": "index"
  },

  index: function() {
    var query = location.search;
    // work with query
  }       
});
```

Let me know if you get a problem.

Comment: It seems works but I need to filter string after `?`. Do you advise to make it manually in index callback handler ?

Comment: I don't know if the best solution ever but that's what I'm doing and it's working pretty well , and it's clear

Comment: Ok, let me test your snippet for a while and give you feedback some later.

Comment: Let me know if you found a better method